# Make an async function that runs on load of a specific page

Tags: javascript, php, asynchronous

I am trying to make an async function that runs when a specific pages is loaded, and it also needs to get the newest index from a .txt array db.

```
var latestReceivedTweetId = 0 // 47

window.onload(async function(){
  // let connection = await fetch('api-get-latest-tweets.php?latestReceivedTweetId='+latestReceivedTweetId)
  let connection = await fetch(`api/api-get-latest-tweets.php?latestReceivedTweetId=${latestReceivedTweetId}`)
  console.log(connection)
  if(connection.status != 200){
    alert('Something is wrong in the system')
  }

  let sTweets = await connection.text()
  let aTweets = JSON.parse(sTweets) // PHP json_decode

  for(var i = 0; i < aTweets.length; i++){
    latestReceivedTweetId = aTweets[i].id
    var divTweet = `
    <div class="tweet" id="${aTweets[i].id}">
      <p>${aTweets[i].title}</p>
      <p>${aTweets[i].message}</p>
      <button>delete</button>
    </div>`     
    document.querySelector("#tweets").insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', divTweet)
  }
  console.log('latestReceivedTweetId', latestReceivedTweetId)


})
```

The db are build like this

```
[{"id":"5f5f47b2d8f8f","title":"Hello World","message":"This is a tweet","userId":"5f59ff729184f"},{"id":"5f5fae2aa62b5","title":"New Tweet","message":"This is a new tweet","userId":"5f59ff729184f"},{"id":"5f5fae2cbb02b","title":"New Tweet","message":"This is a new tweet","userId":"5f59ff729184f"},{"id":"5f5fb14bebbc8","title":"Hello World","message":"This is a tweet","userId":"5f59ff729184f"}]
```

If further code insight are needed just ask and i can link to a github with the project.

Comment: why not do `await connection.json()` instead of text() then parse? whats not working?

Comment: It does not put in the"tweet" into the tweets page. I had it working when i made it an interval but then it kept running the interval therefor i was trying to make it only run the script ones the page are loaded.

Comment: I think the onload is wrong shouldn't it be `window.onload = async function() {`